# xsd and wsdl incorrect file

Tags: xsd, wsdl

How to fix corrupted xsd and wsdl files, is there any IDE which can suggest what is wrong? such as eclipse for java code when pressing CTRL + 1 , or where can I find books tutorials to understand formatting of these file types better? thank you

Here is concrete message error I have

```
[ERROR] 'item' is already defined
  line 223 of file:/C:/project/src/main/resources/schema.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 22 of file:/C:/project/src/main/resources/schema.xsd
```